# Item alignments are not proper in horizontal recycler view using grid layout manager

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

The view inside recycler view is not aligned properly. The items inside recyclerview are having different height on adding new item.

I tried of using `display metrics` but could not achieve it. My item list can be changed by adding or deleting items but the view padding, width and height must h=not get disturbed.

```
    categoryRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.categoriesRecyclerView);
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1,GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    categoryRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    categoryRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new ItemDecorator(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.item_spacing), 3));
    CategoryItemAdapter categoryItemAdapter = new CategoryItemAdapter(this, categoryList);
    categoryRecyclerView.setAdapter(categoryItemAdapter);
```

**Code for Adapter**

```
public class CategoryItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryItemAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Category> categoryList;
private onItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

public CategoryItemAdapter(Context context, List<Category> categoryList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.categoryList = categoryList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_item, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryItemAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Category category = (Category) categoryList.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(category.getCategoryName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return categoryList.size();
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
    this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
}

public interface onItemClickListener {
    void onItemClickListener(View view, int position, Category category);
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    CardView cardview;
    TextView textView;
    ImageView selectItem;
    RelativeLayout selectItemLayout;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cardview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
        linearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.llbackground);
        selectItemLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.selectItemLayout);
        selectItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.selectItem);
        selectItemLayout.setVisibility(authenticationHelper.isAdmin() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        Util.setRandomGradientColor(linearLayout, GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mItemClickListener != null) {
            mItemClickListener.onItemClickListener(view, getAdapterPosition(), categoryList.get(getAdapterPosition()));
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**Code for view**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llbackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/category_gradient"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categoryName"
            android:text="Men"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/selectItemLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/selectItem"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:tag="@string/unchecked"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/circle"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Recycler view in activity**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/categoriesRecyclerView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/categoriesLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

[image: output of above code]

Thanks for help!!